# create archive of a git repo with .git

Tags: git

I want to get an archive from a local git repo. The archive should have `.git` directory and should not have any files that are not under the track of git. It should look like what I get with a `git clone` command. I don't want to use `tar` command, because it will include files that are not part of the git repo. I try `git archive`, but it does not include .git metadata. What can I do?

Comment: Take a look at [git-bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

Comment: Why not copy and paste the .git folder somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the extra repo as a remote:

1. Create a new folder and `cd` into it
2. Type `git clone [path to your original repo]`
3. Tar the generated folder

This will make a new folder containing only the files checked in to git, and also a `.git` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to do this is with [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). It creates a file with all of the repository information in a single file. Anyone can then use `git clone` on it to expand it, just like you would with a remote repository.

```bash
cd git-repo
# create the bundle file `repo.bundle`:
git bundle repo.bundle --branches --tags
```

The produced file can then be cloned.

```bash
git clone repo.bundle
```

There are various ways you can configure what goes into the bundle, including which branches and refs are included. The above example includes all of the tags and branches.

You can also update an existing repository with a bundle file. To do this, add it as a remote, and use the normal pull commands:

```
git remote add bundle ../repo.bundle
git pull bundle
```